# Differences between primary and secondary VGA pass through in virtualization

Tags: graphics, virtualization

[Xen](http://wiki.xen.org/wiki/Xen_VGA_Passthrough), and more recently [KVM](http://wiki.qemu.org/ChangeLog/1.5#Device_emulation), allows you to pass a VGA adaptor from the host to the guest as either a primary or secondary device. Both links provide some explanation as to why passing a VGA adaptor through is more difficult than passing a standard PCI device through and to some extent why passing a VGA adaptor through as the primary device is more difficult than passing it through as a secondary device. What are the advantages of passing a VGA adapter through as the primary device as opposed to the secondary device?